# move the BlackBerry focus from code

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have 3 buttons A, B and C. When I click A, the page reloads and the focus will be on A and when I click B, the page reloads and focus will be on B and so on. How do I implement this?

```
if(constants.focuz.equals("next")){ 
          next.setFocus(); 
}else if (constants.focuz.equals("prev")){ 
          prev.setFocus(); 
} else{ 
          abtme.setFocus(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is Ok. You probably call it on a non-UI thread? If yes, then use `UiApplication.invokeLater(Runnable action)` to reset the focus. So it should be something like this:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (constants.focuz.equals("next")) {
            next.setFocus();
        } else if (constants.focuz.equals("prev")) {
            prev.setFocus();
        } else {
            abtme.setFocus();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To set focus for the button field you have to use

`setFocus()` method.

Example code:

```
ButtonField lf=new ButtonField("Button");

lf.setFocus();
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: if(constants.focuz.equals("next")){
next.setFocus();
}else if (constants.focuz.equals("prev")){
prev.setFocus();
}
else{
abtme.setFocus();
}